# Traveling to waypoints without money

Tags: guild-wars-2

Traveling to waypoints in Guild Wars 2 costs money. I've found out that when you don't have money left in your inventory, the money gets taken from your bank.

I was wondering if it would be possible to travel without having money at all? So if you have 0 in your inventory and 0 in the storage, can you still travel?

Comment: If you're trying to save money on travel, remember that you can always get to Lion's Arch for free (by going via WvW or sPvP and then through the waygate to LA) and from LA to any of the other four major cities (plus to Southsun Cove). This will take a bit of time (e.g. the LA loading screen always seems to take forever) but can save you a few coins if you're hard-pressed for money....

Comment: Good call! Do it consistenly to save up 2 silver per travel!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No when you dont have enough money you have to travel on foot. You can however always travel to the nearest waypoint on death. As stated on the gw wiki:

> **Maximum costs when defeated, but broke.**
>
> > If you are defeated, you can
> >     always travel to the nearest waypoint.
> >     If you have no money in inventory, the cost will be deducted from your
> >     bank. If you also have no money in the bank, you will not be charged
> >     beyond what you had left in inventory. If the waypoint is contested,
> >     you will have to wait to travel (or have someone mail you the cost to
> >     travel to the next nearest waypoint). You cannot travel to the mists
> >     while defeated.

[Source](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Waypoint)